# Prove $r^{(k)} = r^{(k-1)} + \alpha_{(k-1)}Ap^{(k-1)}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't seem to show that $r^{(k)} = r^{(k-1)} + \alpha_{(k-1)}Ap^{(k-1)}$, I have tried substituing the definition of $\alpha_{(k-1)}$ but am not being successful. could someone please help?

Comment: I don't think this question provides enough context to understand what it is talking about. How are all those symbols introduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$r^{(k+1)} = b - Ax^{(k+1)} = b - A\left\{x^{(k)} + \alpha_kp^{(k)}\right\} = b - Ax^{(k)} - \alpha_k A p^{(k)} = r^{(k)} - \alpha_k A p^{(k)}$$